Car uses unusual amount of oil
I drive a Renault Megane Grandtour 08 Gen2. I got the K4M Engine with 16V 116ish HP and 1.6L Now 2 Months ago my Oilsensor advised me to add some Oil for the engine and I did add about 1 Liter of the recommended Oiltype from the Manual. I checked with the Dipstick everything was alright. Since then I drove about 6-8k Kilometers and since about a week sometimes it shows me to refill again. But its not always the case and I couldn't reproduce the error. I checked for Water in the Oil by opening the lid and checking for foam. There was obv nothing I couldn't determine different sounds from the engine nor can I see blue smoke from the Engine or the exhaustpipe. I wonder if the Sensor is defect. How can I verify this? Is there another reason this might be? I usually drive the same road every day and tried to see if i take a sharp turn, acceleration or break would trigger the sensor to hit sadly no consistency. Also the enginetemp does not really add into this. I checked with the Dipstick again and it is okayish right in the middle between High and Min. Oh and to wrap everything up I could not find any leak
Edit: Since my question in the beginning regards the consumption: When I checked the oil after the first refill it was on High since then it wandered to the middle. Can 6-8k really be realistically? does this combined joins in on the problem with my sensor?

Your ('08?) car is 14yrs old and how many kms? Presuming a well used vehicle, oil consumption can occur early or later since maintenance and driving varies in determining oil usage. The easiest way to check your oil level indicator is from baseline info; off with dipstick showing full, checking dipstick level when the oil sensor turns on. If a liter is used to top off from oil sensor indicator, correlate top up with odometer mileage from last top up. The added mileage with the next oil low indicator determines oil usage per mileage between fill up. 6k-8k kms is not unusual. Check car forums.

My Renault has ran about 152k km by now or 94,4k Miles by now so he didnt really get used. I bought him about 6 Months ago had the same car with similar (180k km) beforehand and drove that one 20k km before i unfortunatley had a crash and never had to top him off with any oil (keep in mind same engine same production year)
But i will check for your suggestion with the immeadiate checking. I didn't do that until now and always waited until everything cooled down so i have no thermal expansion which ruins my measurment but i will try thank you

1 l per 6000–8000 km would be around 0.1–0.2 l/1000 km. The upper limit (as per the manual for my car) is 0.5 l/1000 km, around 3–4 times your oil consumption. Are you seeing blue smoke coming from your exhaust? This would be a sign your engine is burning oil (i.e. more than just trace amounts). Is your engine compartment oily? That would indicate oil leakage.

@user149408 that sounds like my car is really dry compared to yours. I already checked for smoke in normal driving i can't find any blue smoke. He barley smokes at all except when i obv put it under pressure (like driving up a hill) i get a small burst of smoke but nothing blue. (I mean obv it smokes when i press it) tried the advice from F Dryer. It seems like he is leaking some oil somewhere. He lost in about 1k a little more than in the manual referenced so it must leak. I guess a small leak in the pipes which is not noticable when he stands. Again i checked the ground there was no oil
